# Check if the given set is a subspace or not (Set of polynomial functions)

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The set of polynomial functions over a field $F$, of order $n$ or less than $n$, that satisfy in each case the given condition:

1. $2 f(0)- 3 f(1) = 0$

My thinking: This is not a subspace because of the scalar multiplication.
$2 f(0)- 3 f(1) = 0$ can be viewed as: $f(1) = (2/3) f(0)$. And when you have a function $f(x)$, and do the scalar multiplication of an k belonging to the field $F$, the condition works only when $k=1$.

2. $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+...+f(k)=0$

I've got no idea how to tackle this part.

Comment: Good to see you've added your thinking. Now, scalar multiplication does no harm to the condition whatsoever, because if $2f(0)=3f(1)$, and you  multiply by some $k$ in the field, then $2(kf)(0)=(2k)f(0)=k(2f(0))=k(3f(1))=3(kf)(1)$, so scalar multiplication doesn't affect your property. Similarly, the other condition additivity doesn't (prove it for yourself), and so your set is infact a subspace. The second one,for similar reasons, should be a subspace as well (put $kf$ in place of $f$, the equality doesn't change, and additivity follows similarly).

Comment: If $f$ is in your first space, do we have that $kf$ is in that space? What about $f+g$, where $g$ is another element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an abstract nonsense proof. Think about it!

If $V$ is some  vector space  of functions $f:\>F\to F$, where $F$ is a field, then for any $a\in F$ the evaluation map
$$\delta_a:\quad V\to F,\qquad f\mapsto f(a)$$
is a linear functional on $V$ (hence an element of the dual space $V^*$) by the way addition and scaling of functions is defined. It follows that any linear combination $\phi$ of such $\delta_a$s is in $V^*$, hence ${\rm ker}(\phi)$ is a subspace of $V$.